# If I want to keep 30+ apps updated in Google console, how do I use Google play developer API?

Tags: python, android, google-api, google-developers-console

Currently I have published 20 apps in Google store and I plan to expand the number to 40+ apps.

I need to be able to massively update all apps on production efficiently and quicker than using the Google developers console.

Which is the more convenient way to update all published apps having the apk files on storage? I've read the documentation of the Google Play developer API and I'm thinking some way to write a Python script using requests or some similar library but I've never used the APIs from Google.

My goal is to automate the process of uploading each new version of each app one by one. They all update at the same time with the same version, and have exactly the same promotion text except for the app name as a variable. This is because the apps are all the same but what it changes is the brand in each one.

Any help is more than welcome.

Thanks

Comment: I certainly do not know the answer, but one option might be to look at task automation. I'll link an example software that handles this, but I by no means specifically recommend this product. https://robotask.com/ - There are dozens of variations of these task automation robots.

Comment: Thanks i'll take a look at the tool